# Increasing size of circles in ggplot2 graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to increase the scale of circles in `ggplot2`. I tried something like this `aes(size=100*n)` but it did not work for me.

```
df <-
      structure(list(Logit = c(-2.9842723737754, 1.49511606166294, 
    -2.41756623714116, -2.96160412831003, -2.12996384688938, -1.61751836789074, 
    -0.454353048358851, 0.9284099250287, -0.144082412641708, -2.30422500981431, 
    -0.658367257547178, 0.082600042011989, -0.318343575566633, -0.717447827238429, 
    -1.0508122312565, -2.82559465551781, 0.361703788394458, -1.85086010050691, 
    -0.0916611209129359, -0.740116072703798, 0.0599317965466193, 
    -0.370764867295404, -0.703703748477917, -0.749040239408657, -2.7575899191217, 
    -2.51532401980067, 1.38177483433609, 1.47244781619757, -0.205002348239784, 
    0.135021333740761), PRes = c(-0.661648371860934, 1.63444424896772, 
    -0.30348016008728, -0.230651042355737, 1.07487559116003, -0.460143991337599, 
    -0.823052248365889, -0.999903730870253, -0.959022180953211, -0.321344960297977, 
    -1.40881799070885, -0.674754839222841, 0.239931843185434, -1.81660411888874, 
    0.830318780187542, -0.24702802619469, 0.692695708496924, -0.40412065378683, 
    -0.977640032689132, -0.715192962242284, -1.06270128658429, -0.856103053117159, 
    -0.731162073769824, 1.51334938767359, 4.02946801536109, 3.56902361409375, 
    0.505952430753934, 0.483660641952208, 1.13712619443209, 0.951889504154342
    ), n = c(7L, 38L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 
    8L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L)), .Names = c("Logit", "PRes", "n"), row.names = c(NA, -30L
    ), class = "data.frame")


    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(x=Logit, y=PRes, label=rownames(df))) + 
      geom_point(aes(size=n), shape=1, color="black") + 
      geom_text() +
      theme_bw() + 
      theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a scale for size:

```
+ scale_size_continuous(range = c(10, 15))
```

[image]

Comment: (+1): Great, thanks for nice answer. Using `scale_size_continuous(range = range(df$n))` would be more appropriate.

Comment: If that suits your needs, of course. One note though: range for scale is given in size units, which are not always directly 1:1 with range of the data.